# ZFS, aufs automount and Samba

Tags: samba, automount, zfs

I have a server running 14.04 and ZFS (the zpool is mounted as `/home`). Each user's home folder contains a `media` folder, which I want to merge using Aufs (e.g., `/srv/media`) and then serve (read-only) via Samba.

Now, since the zpool isn't listed in `/etc/fstab`, it must be imported at some other point during boot-up. What I want to do is make sure things happen in the right order:

1. The zpool is imported.
2. The aufs merge point is mounted.
3. The Samba share is mounted.

How do I do that? For that matter, how do I find out where in the boot process the zpool is imported?